# How to navigate to specific fragment in another android application?

Tags: android, android-intent

Say for example if I have application A and application B. Is it possible for me to navigate from application A to a SPECIFIC fragment in application B by using intent? How should I do that?

Comment: Application A and Application B are both yours?

Comment: Yes both apps are created by me